# How to create a videoCapture object in a class

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use a VideoCapture object in a class , all the examples that i have seen are setting the camera id in the constructor of the object.

```
cv::VideoCapture cam(1);
```

if i declare the object  as a  class variable

```
 cv::VideoCapture cam
```

how can i initialize it in the class constructor to camID = 1;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this weird colon-member (" : ") syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Comment: Call cv::VideoCapture with  your class constructor using  cam index as parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize it by using [open](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#abd88ea03aad64f7f00f3767e8b8c2034) :

```
class InitialiseTest
{    
    VideoCapture cap;    
public:
    InitialiseTest(){
        cap.open(1);
    }        
};

int main()
{    
    InitialiseTest obj;
    
}
```